# String extraction from body of email

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to extract information from the body of an email.

The email is not consistent in format. The code is returning ZERO values in certain cases.

Here is the current iteration of code.

```
Sub CopyToExcel()
     Dim xlApp As Object
     Dim xlWB As Object
     Dim xlSheet As Object
     Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
     Dim vText As Variant
     Dim sText As String
     Dim vItem As Variant
     Dim oText As Variant
     Dim oItem As String

     Dim i As Long
     Dim rCount As Long
     Dim bXStarted As Boolean
     enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
     'the path of the workbook
     strPath = enviro & "\Documents\TEST.xlsx"

     If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
       End If
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
       Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
     Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     bXStarted = True
       End If
     On Error GoTo 0
    'Open the workbook to input the data
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

     'Process each selected record
       rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        oText = Split(olItem.Subject, ":")
        sText = olItem.Body
        vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
       'Find the next empty line of the worksheet

          oItem = Trim(oText(1))
          If Len(oText(1)) = 0 Then oText(1) = ""
          'Check each line of text in the message body
          For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1



         If InStr(1, vText(i), "-") > 0 Then
                     vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(45))
                     xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = oText(1)
                     xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(0))
                     xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))

            End If
          Next i
       xlWB.Save
         rCount = rCount + 1
       Next olItem
       xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
       If bXStarted Then
          xlApp.Quit
      End If
      Set xlApp = Nothing
      Set xlWB = Nothing
      Set xlSheet = Nothing
      Set olItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

The code works with this email.

> *"Dear Sir/Madam,We wish to confirm that **107.34** STG will be lodged to your nominated bank account. This is in full and final settlement of your claim.
>   **107.34 - 000001017660912***
>   *John Smith On behalf of the Company."*

It finds the amount paid and the invoice number and adds it to an Excel spreadsheet. I have bolded the data required.

In the example below the **`"-"`** character that helps the Split function is not present and the If function returns False.

> *"Dear Sir/Madam,We wish to confirm that **143.81** STG will be lodged to your nominated bank account. This is in full and final settlement of your claim.
>   **000001017671676**
>
>   JOHN SMITH On behalf of the Company."*

Comment: Is this the data your trying to pull? https://regex101.com/r/S4JTTP/1

Comment: Looks like it is. I only require one instance of the amount to be captured. As the amount can be duplicated in the body of the email.

Comment: The only one thing to note the match criteria you have pointed out is that the amount can be made up of two to three digits, the Match function is looking to a three character string.

Comment: \s(\d{1,3}\.\d{2,3})\s|\s(\d{15})\s    You can specify ranges in the regex @0m3r gave...

Comment: Is  000001017660912 the invoice? So for every e-mail you want the amount and this long invoice number? Is the length of the invoice number fixed?

Comment: indeed , the invoice number will always stay the same number of digits. The bad thing about all this is the fact that i have no idea how to implement this using regex. Even the most clued up person on VBA in the company is not that proficient using regex.

Comment: the regex @0m3r gave and the variation I mentioned is a starter. For the other, as it is 15 digits with a gap either side you are looking for something like \d{15}\s   Tbh, I haven't tried VBA regex with range but imagine you can do {1,3}